# Can I include a C library in a Qt Creator Android application?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

**Summary**

Basically, I want to include a C or C++ libraries into my Qt Creator project, and then build for both Windows and Android. Without the library I'm currently able to build with no problems.

**More Information**

I'm attempting to develop a cross-platform application for both Window x86 desktop, and an Android application. I have successfully integrated the .lib file into Windows desktop application with Qt Creator. I have some .so library files, but I believe those files are Java library files.

**End Goals**

I'd either like to compile a Linux version of libraries for use in C++ with Qt Creator, or include the .so files for use with Java. The only thing that troubles me with the latter is being able to switch between libraries in the same code base. Plus, I'm not sure how to include Java code in a Qt project for Android. Primarily, keeping everything in C++ for both Windows and Android is preferred.

Comment: .so files are typically *nix shared libraries, sort of the *nix version of a Windows DLL. Java libraries are typically .jar files. Whether you can use the C library on Android or not is clearly going to depend on what the library does.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm looking to include the libVlc library. It allows media playback.

Comment: Yes, you can use a C library.  You have to access it using JNI to call from Java to C, which may (probably will) require you to write a thin C wrapper around the library.

Comment: Generally you'd build a Qt app for Android completely in C++, no Java is necessary. That said, Android supports multiple architectures (ARM, ARM64, x86, etc.) so you'll need the .so library built for each architecture you want to support.